# How to avoid the initial GET of an img tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When loading the page the following error occurs:

[image: Error 404]

```html
<div class="row" ng-show="showChannels">
  <div ng-repeat="content in formChannels" class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="well alignCenter" ng-click="clickSintonizarCanal($index)">
      <img src="{{content.images.image[0].url}}" class="img-responsive imgchannel" alt="{{$index}}">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand that is because when you start the page "formChannels" is null.
then when formChannels already has a value, everything works OK.

my question is, how do I avoid this unnecessary GET?

there is some way "Standar", Elegant, or simple to do it?

AngularJS has something for these cases?

thank you very much to all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use ng-src.  This will create the src attribute once it is ready.

```
<img ng-src="{{content.images.image[0].url}}" />
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the ng-src directive. That way the browser won't try and load the image until angular has been bootstrapped. See here for documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

So your image tag will look like this:

```
<img ng-src="{{content.images.image[0].url}}" class="img-responsive imgchannel" alt="{{$index}}">
```